# saving, manipulating and restoring std::ios_base::fmtflags

Tags: c++, flags

My function gets an `std::ostream& stream` as an input parameter, sends the data into it, and returns the `stream`. In the function I would like to manipulate the flags of the stream but want to restore them as I leave the function:

```
   stream << "| 1:" << 3.1234567890 << "|" ;
   stream << std::endl;
   // geting the flags up to now
   std::ios_base::fmtflags f = stream.flags();
   // setting the flags the way we like it
   stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9);
   stream << "| 2:" << 3.1234567890 << "|" ;
   stream.setf(f);
   stream << std::endl;
   stream << "| 3:" << 3.1234567890 << "|" ;
```

Now the output (surprisengly) is:

```
| 1:3.12346|
| 2:3.123456789|
| 3:3.123456789|
```

once I set `stream` to `std::cout`. Clearly I was not able to restore the flags with `stream.setf(f)`. Why? What's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ios_base::flags` is the function you're looking for, both
to read and restore.  `std::ios_base::setf` will only set flags;
it won't unset any (and it can create some really strange values
in the multibit flags, like base and float format).  In
addition, you'll probably want to save and restore the precision
(which isn't part of the flags) and possibly the fill character.
The usual way of doing this is with something like:

```
class SaveIOFmt
{
    std::basic_ios<char>& myOwner;
    std::basic_ios<char>::fmtflags myFlags;
    int myPrecision;
    char myFill;

    SaveIOFmt( SaveIOFmt const& );
    SaveIOFmt& operator=( SaveIOFmt const& );

public:
    SaveIOFmt( std::basic_ios<char>& owner )
        : myOwner( owner )
        , myFlags( owner.flags() )
        , myPrecision( owner.precision() )
        , myFill( owner.fill() )
    {
    }
    ~SaveIOFmt()
    {
        myOwner.fill( myFill );
        myOwner.precision( myPrecision );
        myOwner.flags( myFlags );
    }
};
```

Then all you do is define an instance of this class at the top
of your code, and everything will be restored when you leave,
regardless of how you leave.

Comment: I am getting an error `'class std::ios_base' has no member named 'fill'` though (under `g++ --version: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`). Any commments?

Comment: My mistake.  It should be `std::basic_ios<char>` for the stream type.  (My actual code is relatively old, and uses a typedef here, so I didn't see the actual type.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd add that if you are willing/able to use the Boost library there is no need to roll your own solution here: [IO State Savers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html).